# Performance: Async vs Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I know that Async and threads are two very different things as the first is for developing Asynchronous behaviors while the other is for Synchronous or parallel functions. But one thing that I have noticed just now is that when the aim is to keep the application responsive and alive during long running tasks, when using Async and Await there is considerable less CPU usage that doing the old way with thread like this:

```
Thread Task1 = new Thread(()=>{

      // Do Something 
});

Thread Task2 = new Thread(()=>{
      Task1.Start();
      while(true){
         if (!Task1.IsAlive){
             // Do something 
             break;
         }
         Thread.Sleep(50);
      }
});
```

I just wanna know if it is normal to see that Async has a higher performance, because I think the same senario is going on in the background for Async tasks. Using the same delay miliseconds (50) for both:

```
Thread.Sleep(50) -> thread
await Task.Delay(50) -> Async
```

on a performance test application I observed about less 5% CPU usage on Async for doing the same operation.

Comment: You are comparing oranges to apples. You need to clarify your question as your code example does two different things.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: no both code run two task Asynchronously, look at them again. The thread waits for the Task one to finish before running something else. Same is done in Async as it awaits. But Async consumes less CPU.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` don't do the same thing.

Comment: What I find oddest about this approach is that you're comparing two different ways of *doing nothing* by looking at *CPU usage*. Not sure what you're trying to prove or disprove by this approach.

Comment: @StephenCleary: When using Async (I think but not sure) the compiler must create a thread in the background and when you make your own thread it actually has to be the same. But imagine that `what you mentioned as nothing` is just a silly infinite loop with `Console.WriteLine` inside of it. If you do this loop test using both thread and async (I can show you how I mean), the thread consumes more CPU. Assuming what Yuval said is true about Task.Delay, what is the magic behind it. The reason why I say this is because both Thread.Sleep and Task.Delay are to postpone the execution of something.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I'm not trying to approve or disprove something, I just wanna know the reason for what I have experienced in case anyone may know the answer.

Comment: @Ricky: No, `async` does not create a thread. It's just a convenient way to do asynchronous operations. I/O is a good example of a naturally asynchronous operation; CPU-bound code is not. So, in The Real World (tm), the CPU performance of async generally doesn't matter, because any CPU time would be absolutely dwarfed by the time spent doing the asynchronous operation.

Comment: When implemented correctly, there's likely to be zero significant/measurable difference between an asynchronous operation that uses `async`/`await` vs some older mechanism. But your code seems to have a thread dedicated to waking up every 50ms just to see if some other thread is still working. Without a good code example, it's not possible to know what you're trying to achieve, but even without that, given the code you did post it's pretty much guaranteed your non-`async` implementation is incorrect. So it's not much surprise it's less efficient than one using `async` support.

Answer (score 0):

From " to keep the application responsive" I conclude that you talk about some Windows program.

In this case async/await will run **in the same UI thread** as the rest of the program. The windows dispatcher will execute the async part along with the rest **sequentially**.
(The continuation code after the async operation itself will run on the UI thread)

On the other hand, a backgorund worker (thread) will run **in parallel** and probably on another core (nowadays).

Anyway, CPU usage tells you **nothing** about whats going on.

Comment: "The windows dispatcher will execute the async part along with the rest sequentially" -- this is not correct. Asynchronous operations, by definition, do not use the current thread. Plus, some don't even use any thread; they just take advantage of existing OS mechanisms to allow an operation to complete independent of any running thread in the process. You seem to be confusing the async operation itself with the continuation mechanism (i.e. what happens after an `await` statement completes), where the continuation is by default executed in the UI thread.